# jpa delete error using 2 @param with id and id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

this is my code
[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqFfA.png)

im dont understand, i think i already made similar in
'comment' and 'cart'
my problem in 'comment'

[this is example my cart entity with attribute order_identifier and product_id and this is success to delete by this two attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Cxc.png)

but after when im made similar in comment this error show up
is this error because using two @param with 2 attribute id?
im not find the answer anywhere yet, whoever you help me to fix my concept im really appreciate it :')

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract void com.demo.lookopediaSinarmas.repositories.CommentRepository.deleteCommentByUserIdAndProductId(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long) but parameter 'Optional[product_id]' not found in annotated query 'delete from comment where product_id:=product_id and user_id=:user_id'!

Comment: Don't put pictures of code. You wouldn't put stories of your vacation pictures either.

Comment: ouh.. ok, i think i repost my comment without picture of code thanks

Comment: Hi mystic, wellcome to SO, please, use pastebin or a GitHub repo to show us the code and full stacktrace. Thank you.

Comment: You have to replace `product_id:=product_id` with `product_id=:product_id`

Answer (score 1):

At `line 20` by using `:` after `=` will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Valid query is

```
delete from comment where product_id=:product_id and user_id=:user_id
```